# Spoj NZEC error

Tags: java, primes

This is my code for prime generation:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class prime_gen
{

public static void gen_prime(long min,long max)
{

   long n=max/2,i=0,j=0;

        boolean[] prime = new boolean[(int) max];        
 if(min==1)
{

System.out.println("2");
System.out.println("3");

}
else
if(min==3)
System.out.println("3");
else
if(min==2)
{
System.out.println("2");
System.out.println("3");
}

        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            for (j = i; j <= (n - i) / (2 * i + 1); j++)
                prime[(int) (i + j + 2 * i * j)] = true;


for (i = 2; i < prime.length/2; i++)
        {
              if (!prime[(int)i])
                  {
                        if(2*i+1>min)

              System.out.println((2*i+1)+" ");
       }






}
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
try
{
int i=0,T=0;
long[] min,max;
String[] s1=new String[2];
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s=br.readLine();
T=Integer.parseInt(s);
min=new long[T];
max=new long[T];

for(i=0;i<T;i++)
{
s1=br.readLine().split(" ");
min[i]=Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);
max[i]=Integer.parseInt(s1[1]);



}

for(i=0;i<T;i++)
{
gen_prime(min[i],max[i]);
System.out.println();
}
}catch(Exception e)
{
return;

}   }

}
```

The constraints are:

```
T<=10
max<=1000000000
max-min<=100000
```

I use the sieve of sundaram for prime generation and the code works fine for my test cases.I have also used the try catch block to handle exceptions.I don't know what's wrong in this code.The spoj forum says the NZEC error is thrown whenever an exception is generated by the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above code works fine for smaller input but have you checked for `corner or extreme cases` that you deal with??when you will check it with `extreme cases` you will find that you code is giving `runtime error` for them..try it on [ideone](http://ideone.com) you will get runtime error..now what is the problem for this??think of a single test case where we have the input

> 999900000 1000000000

now according to your code

```
n = max / 2 = 1000000000 / 2 = 500000000
```

now directly moving to your `for loop`

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        for (j = i; j <= (n - i) / (2 * i + 1); j++)
            prime[(int) (i + j + 2 * i * j)] = true;
```

considering the last value (always think of extrema) for the outer loop when

```
i = 500000000 (although `i` will be 1 less than this value ,I am considering it for simplicity as it will have not considerable effect and make our calculations easier)
j = i
```

now the index you are handling for `prime` array is now for the first value of `j`

```
prime[(int) (i + j + 2 * i * j)] = 500000000 + some positive number
```

the size of array in any programming language is not that large(i don't know about JAVA) ..its about `10^6` `maximum`(can be more in JAVA)..so you are accessing the index that cannot be managed..that's the reason you are getting `runtime error`..you have to change your approach..

now one more thing that I will point out is the complexity of `Sieve of Sundaram` which is

> O(n * log n)

while `Sieve of Eratosthenes` has a complexity

> O(n * log(log n))

So I think you should use `Sieve of Eratosthenes` because `Sieve of Sundaram` **might** lead to `TLE`..But `Sieve of Eratosthenes` will not only be sufficient..you have to use `segmented sieve` for this problem..there may be another methods also by which you will be able to solve this problem.

**EDIT 1**:- not going beyond you have used

```
boolean[] prime = new boolean[(int) max];
```

on the above line only as soon as you enter the test case mentioned by me you will get `runtime error` as creating such a large array is not allowed on the `coding websites`

**EDIT 2**:- I ran a simple code for finding whether it is possible to have that much memory for array but i don't think so..here is the code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long max = 1000000000;
        boolean[] prime = new boolean[(int) max];
        System.out.println("IT WORKED");
    }
}
```

and here is what I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at Ideone.main(Main.java:13)
```

and the link [to the code](http://ideone.com/FqF89w)..it failed for `10 ^ 9` size of array